# What triggers garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I know what all gets garbage collected. But what exactly tells JRE that it is time for garbage collection? Is it like some event or time interval?

Comment: Surely someone has asked this before...yep.

Answer (score 8):

HotSpot's garbage collection has grown into an exceedingly complex business, which even its creators struggle to understand in full detail. Therefore you can't be given a simple answer; some triggers are:

1. occupation of each object generation reaching a threshold;
2. a memory allocation request *in a specific generation* failing;
3. overall heap occupation reaching a threshold.

Note that you haven't even specified what *kind* of garbage collection you are interested in: there is a *minor* collection and a *major* collection, and technologically they are very different. You have also not specified which Garbage Collector you have in mind: HotSpot has four of them to choose from.

If you are a beginner with Java, the best advice to give is a) in day-to-day programming, don't worry about it; and b) if you want to learn, you'll have to [dig deep](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140228.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.gc();` but there's no guarantee that it'll run (it just "suggests" to the GC to run).

The JVM has different implementations, including the GC which can be run in different modes, and has very complex algorithms which usually work pretty good, that said, if you have a special usage (or special events, like after a restart of a platform) - you can tune it [*using flags*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html) (like: minimum heap size, maximum heap size and etc), but even without doing so, the GC collects objects that have null reference (pointers that points to them) whenever there's a need to free memory from the heap.

Comment: You really should not use System.gc. The JVM knows better when to do GC than you do. There are some corner cases where it can be justified calling System.gc but most of the time developers should not do it.

Comment: @pushy totally agree with you!

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that `System.gc()` does way more than just suggest something. I noticed that measuring my `Runtime.freeMemory()` every 10s it was declining over many minutes to get freed "randomly". Adding a `System.gc()` every 10s basically kills most of my `freeMemory()` from the start.

Comment: @Giszmo even though you responded to a comment from almost 10 years ago, I believe that the recommendation is still the same: don't use `System.gc()`

Answer (score 0):

I thing as a good practices dont fully depend on GC,See [THIS](http://www.javatpoint.com/Garbage-Collection) OR [THIS](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The JVM controls the Garbage collector, it decides when to run the Garbage Collector. It will run the GC when it realizes that the memory is *running low* or an object become eligible for GC when no *live thread* can access it.

But this behavior of JVM cannot be guaranteed, one can request the GC to happen from within the java program but there is no guarantee that this request will be taken care by JVM.

Comment: The first part is right, Java will do GC when memory runs low. But Java does not know when an object becomes eligible for GC (this decision is made in the GC itself). If a mark/sweep collector is used, it will of course mark dead objects and run a sweep on them if necessary, but that is part of GC.

Comment: @pushy: you're right, I misunderstood  between *when* an object eligible for GC and when the JVM *runs* GC, thanks for the note .

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection in java happen when `JVM` thinks it needs a garbage collection based on Java [heap size](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html).

But you can force GC to collect garbage using

```
System.gc ()
```

or

```
Runtime.gc ()
```

But it’s not guaranteed that garbage collection will happen.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html#ixzz2Y9gKzQE1

Comment: You are not "forcing" garbage collection. As you say yourself: there is no guarantee. I think **request** is the better word here.

Answer (score -1):

object has null reference then it will garbage collected. but GC does not give guarantee like when it is done.