# Java 8 sequential streams increase CPU usage very high

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, threadpool, deadlock

In my spring boot service, I am validating incoming orders based upon order details and customer details.

In customer details, I have different lists of objects like Services, Attributes, Products, etc. and for every list, I am doing something like below:

```
products.stream()  
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)  
       .map(Product::getResource)  
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)  
       .filter(<SimplePredicate>)  
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am using streams like this many times for products, services & attributes. We observed that performance-wise it is giving very high TPS and memory usage is also very optimal. But this is consuming CPU very much. We are running the service in Kubernetes pods and it is taking 90% of the CPU provided.

One more interesting observation is, the more CPU we give, TPS achieved is higher and CPU usage also reaches 90%.

Is it because Streams consume more CPU? Or is it because of high Garbage Collection because after every iteration of Streams the internal memory might be garbage collected?

**EDIT-1:**

Upon further investigation using Load Testing, it is observed that:

- Whenever we increase concurrent threads, due to high CPU usage the service starts not responding and followed by a sudden decrease in CPU and thus resulting in low TPS.
- Whenever we decrease concurrent threads, CPU usage still remains high but the service is performing in the most optimal way i.e. high TPS.

The following are the statistics of TPS vs. CPU under different CPU/thread configuration.

CPU: 1500m, Threads:70

```
| TPS | 176  | 140 | 125 | 79 | 63 |
|----------------------------------|
| CPU | 1052 | 405 | 201 | 84 | 13 |
```

CPU: 1500m, Threads:35

```
| TPS | 500 | 510 | 500 | 530 |
|-----------------------------|
| CPU | 1172| 1349| 1310| 1214|
```

CPU: 2500m, Threads:70

```
| TPS |  20 |  20 |  25 |  28 | 26 |
|----------------------------------|
| CPU | 2063| 2429| 2303| 879 | 35 |
```

CPU: 2500m, Threads:35

```
| TPS | 1193 | 1200 | 1200 | 1230 |
|---------------------------------|
| CPU | 600  | 1908 | 2044 | 1949 |
```

**Tomcat Configuration Used:**

```
server.tomcat.max-connections=100
server.tomcat.max-threads=100
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=5
```

**EDIT-2:**
The thread dump analysis says: 80% of the `http-nio` threads are in `Waiting on condition` state. That means all the threads are waiting for something and no one is consuming any CPU that explains low CPU usage. **But what could be causing the threads going for waiting? I'm not using any Asynchronous Calls in the service also.** Even I'm not using any parallel streams, only sequential streams as mentioned above.

The following is the Thread dump when CPU and TPS go down:

```
"http-nio-8090-exec-72" #125 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f014001e800 nid=0x8f waiting on condition [0x00007f0158ae1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: **TIMED_WAITING** (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000d7470b10> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:89)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Comment: What is your *"higher cpu usage"* comparison relative to? A for-loop?

Comment: @ernest_k I am talking with respect to other services without streams. This service is no different from other, the only thing I have used streams and optionals instead of for-loop and if conditions.

Comment: And how do you know that this behavior is because of streams? What about the database and queries, connection pools, consumed external services, etc?

Comment: @fps There is no database call, calling only 1 external service running on the same server without showing any unusual behavior. I doubt this is because of Streams & Optionals because there is nothing special in the service except there are streams instead of for loops and Optional.ofNullable() instead of if() conditions etc.

Comment: @mukund Please get the thread that's consuming more CPU and get the jStack. From the Stack, for the threadId(convert the threadId to Hex) and view the thread dump. When I generated a million ints in my good old mac, CPU is 0.0%. Maybe the GC is taking more CPU? Check if you are using G1GC, also enable GC flags and collect GC stats.

Comment: There is a nice and simple to use profiling tool: https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler

It will show you an exact reason of high cpu usage, including native libraries, JVM internals, GC and even JIT.

Comment: Assuming that TPS means "transactions per second", it makes sense that if you see high TPS rates, CPU usage is also high. Concerning memory usage, it really strongly depends on what your service does. If TPS drops dramatically when increasing the number of threads, this might indicate that those threads are "fighting for resources" such as locks, pooled database connections, file I/O resources or similar. Maybe you are running into (temporary) deadlock, livelock or other type of resource starvation. Without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I cannot say anything more concrete.

Comment: The "waiting on condition" thread status also seems to point into the direction on resource starvation or live/dead-lock. That in this case you still see high CPU usage despite low TPS could mean that the remaining (active) threads take all the CPU resources they can get in order to do their respective jobs.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks. Yes, looks like threads are waiting for some locks (updated thread dump) with TIMED_WAITING status. When 50% or above threads go into this state, then we start to get `SocketTimeoutException: Read Timed Out` and then CPU/TPS goes down. But from the thread dump, I'm not able to understand what causes the threads to reach at `java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos`

Comment: Your threads are concurrently waiting for a locked object to become available. Maybe your products and product resources are used by parallel worker threads, but are not implemented in a thread-safe way. You are having a multi-threaded situation even without parallel execution, just by virtue of using multiple worker threads. If those threads concurrently access common objects synchronised upon in a way causing deadlocks or livelocks, you get the situation described here. Without access to your code I really cannot say more, so if you cannot share a reproducer you have to find out by yourself.

Comment: Do any of your threads from the dump have "locked ownable synchronizers", maybe even the ones the others are waiting for (in this case 0x00000000d7470b10)? Maybe if you post a complete thread dump somewhere and link to it here, somewhere can inspect it and tell you more.

Comment: @kriegaex Please refer to the new SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573120/deadlock-in-embedded-tomcat-server

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "CPU: 1500m" and "CPU: 2500m"?  And what are the units in your CPU measures in the tables?  And how are you measuring that?

Comment: @StephenC, I think he's deploying them in Containerized environments so 1500m refers to 1500 milli-cores. Usually 1000 milli-cores are considered as 1 vCPU.

Comment: @mukund Did you try increasing the number of connections that your server can accept ? Even the default spring-boot config for regular apps is 200 threads + 10k connections. Now you don't need to go to 10k right away but with 1.5-2.5 cores allocated to your container, you can easily handle more connections and more requests as most of your threads are waiting on response from a different service. By the way, did you rule out the possibilities of some other process from your OS consuming CPU while your app is put under load ? Did you confirm that it's your java process consuming high CPU ?

Comment: Well, unless the OP clarifies the various points raised in the later comments, he is unlikely to get answers with anything other than generalities.  Seems like he is wasting his bounty points :-)

Comment: @StephenC, I agree. So why did you write an answer containing generalities a few minutes before the bounty expires? Speculating on getting it anyway? I asked so many questions, explained so much in my comments already and even commented on the spawned off question the OP asked - no reaction there whatsoever. He is wasting his bounty points, we are wasting our precious time, trying to help someone who does not want to take the trouble to cooperate any further.

Comment: well you dont get 600k reputation for commenting on questions, thats for sure ;-)

Comment: @kriegaex - Because I think that my generalities are likely to be helpful.  Not as helpful as if the OP was more specific, but helpful enough to justify the effort I spent on writing it.  (Also ... my comment was intended to spur the OP into answering.  It didn't work, but that too was worth a try.)

Comment: @T.Neidhart, maybe I am not doing everything here for the reputation points. My questions are a means to an end, but they depend on the OP's collaboration. If sometimes I choose not to answer because I am not content with speculating and I do so at the possible expense of some reputation points not gained, I am fine with that. If you would be fine with it too, I would be grateful. Maybe I am more picky with which kinds of questions I honour by answering them, rewarding the OPs' collaboration. I spend limited time here for my own recreation and I decide how to spend it. OK? 

Comment: We should not be making assumptions and remarks about other people's motivations in an answering questions ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because Streams consume more CPU? Or is it because of high Garbage Collection because after every iteration of Streams the internal memory might be garbage collected?

Clearly streams do consume CPU.  And generally speaking, code implemented using non-parallel streams does run a bit slower than code implemented using old-fashioned loops.  However, the difference in performance is not huge.  (Maybe 5 or 10%?)

In general, a stream does not generate more garbage than an old-fashioned loop performing the same computation.   For instance if we compared your example with a loop doing the same thing (i.e. generating a new list), then I would expect there to be a 1-to-1 correspondence between the memory allocations for the two versions.

In short, I don't think streams are directly implicated in this.  Obviously, if your service is processing a lot of lists (using streams or loops) for each request, then that is going to affect the TPS.  And even more so if the lists are actually fetched from your backend database.  But that's normal too.  This could be addressed by doing things like request caching, and tweaking the granularity of API requests to compute expensive results that the caller doesn't actually need.

(I would NOT recommend adding `parallel()` to your streams in your scenario.  Since your service are already compute (or swap) bound, there are no "spare" cycles to run the streams in parallel.  Using `parallel()` here is likely to *reduce* your TPS.)

The second part of your question is about performance (TPS) versus the thread count versus (we think) VCPUs.  It is not possible to interpret the results you have given because you don't explain the units of measurements, and .... because I suspect that there other factors in play.

However, as a general rule:

- Adding more threads when an application is compute intensive doesn't help.
- More threads means more memory utilization (thread stacks + objects only reachable from thread stacks).
- More memory utilization means the GC will be less ergonomic.
- If your JVM is using more virtual memory than you have physical memory, then the OS will typically have to swap pages from RAM to disk and back.  This impacts on performance, especially during garbage collection.

It is also possible that there are effects that can be attributed to your cloud platform.  For example, if your are running in a virtual server on a compute node with lots of virtual servers, you many not get a full CPU's worth per VCPU.  And if your virtual server is generating a lot of swap traffic, that will most likely reduce your server's share of the CPU resources even further.

We cannot say what is actually causing your problem, but if I was in your shoes I would be looking at the Java GC logs, and using OS tools like `vmstat` and `iostat` to look for signs of excessive paging and excessive I/O in general.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because Streams consume more CPU?

I assume you mean: Consume Streams more CPU than loops?
It seems there is not much difference, if loop and stream are doing the same things.
Depending on the exact case there might be small differences. Here are 2 other articles about this question (with this outcome): 
https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html
https://dzone.com/articles/java-performance-for-looping-vs-streaming

> Or is it because of high Garbage Collection because after every iteration of Streams the internal memory might be garbage collected?

Based on your code snippet this question can not be answered. I don't see if some objects are not referenced anymore, so that garbage collection has something to do.
In this question it is explained what triggers the garbage collection:
[What triggers garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483415/what-triggers-garbage-collection)
But your question contains no information about memory usage.

If you want to tune your code, using parallel streams could be an option:

```
products.stream().parallel()  
   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
   ...
```

You will find several articles (e.g. see my first link), which come to conclusion, that there are scenarios, where parallel streams are really faster. So you could try this to increase performance.